# Can i use a custom function with UpdateOne or UpdateMany in MongoDB Shell?

Tags: mongodb-4.0

I wish to perform update on my database using Update command.
the data structure is as following:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d06285570de7d11606275f8"), 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    "ProfilePictures" : [
        {
            "ImageId" : ObjectId("5d0a65d05e82a23764150978"), 
            "CloudinaryUrl" : "<fileAddress>", 
            ...
        }
    ], 
    ...
}
```

i wish to update my URL, for this first i wrote this function:

```
var updateHttpToHttps=function(url){ return url.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://'); }
```

and then i tried to update a new field named `CloudinarySecureUrl` using data from `CloudinaryUrl` field, and then i need to fix mismatch in the `CloudinaryUrl` changing all url starting with `https` to `http`:

```
db.humanResource.user.updateMany({ProfilePictures:{$exists:true}, ProfilePictures:{$ne:null}, ProfilePictures.CloudinaryUrl:{$exists:true}}, {$set:{ProfilePictures.$.CloudinarySecureUrl:updateHttpToHttps(ProfilePictures.$.CloudinaryUrl)}})
```

formatted version:

```
db.humanResource.user.updateMany({
    ProfilePictures: {
        $exists: true
    },
    ProfilePictures: {
        $ne: null
    },
    ProfilePictures.CloudinaryUrl: { // I did this because it said for using $ i have to brign a field from that array to my query
        $exists: true
    }
}, {
    $set: {
        ProfilePictures.$.CloudinarySecureUrl: updateHttpToHttps(ProfilePictures.$.CloudinaryUrl)
    }
})
```

So after writing this update query, i notice, maybe i know that i want to pass the value of `ProfilePictures.$.CloudinaryUrl` to the javascript function used in this update, but it doesn't necesserity mean that it will be processed, since all i write is a query language, not javascript code, so the system cannot pass the value to the function... 
Is there any way to do this? How?

Answer (score 0):

The only way i could find was this, and i ask it in many places, no one answered...:

```
db.humanResource.user.find({
    ProfilePictures: {
        $exists: true
    },
    ProfilePictures: {
        $ne: null
    }
}).forEach(function (e, i) {
    for(var i=0; i< e.ProfilePictures.length; i++){
         e.ProfilePictures[i].CloudinarySecureUrl = updateHttpToHttps(e.ProfilePictures[i].CloudinaryUrl);
         e.ProfilePictures[i].CloudinaryUrl = updateHttpsToHttp(e.ProfilePictures[i].CloudinaryUrl);
    }
    db.humanResource.user.save(e);
})
```

Which is based on the answer of this thread:
[We can use forEach to decrease load on database and Ram Usage, while updating each record, without loading them all, and then we save that document of collection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589792/how-to-replace-substring-in-mongodb-document)

And i could use Print ans JSON stringy as a helping reference before destroying my database:

[JSON.stringify is usable in MongoShell with BSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097209/force-mongodb-to-output-strict-json)

[Print Can be used to print into Mongo Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588006/is-it-possible-to-write-to-mongodb-console-in-javascript-execution)

also there was a `printjson` in the second link, which i didn't notice, at first, i just noticed now.